# Repeat local notification every Monday

Tags: objective-c, xcode, notifications, uilocalnotification

I try to repeat a local notification every Monday. I found `localNotification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;` but I am not sure if it works. How can I show all local notification times in the future?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
[gregorian setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [gregorian components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:today];

[nowComponents setHour:18];
[nowComponents setMinute:05];
[nowComponents setSecond:00];
[nowComponents setWeekday:2];

NSDate * notificationDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:nowComponents];

UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
//localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];
localNotification.fireDate = notificationDate;
localNotification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;
localNotification.soundName = @"localNotification_Sound.mp3";
localNotification.alertBody = @"Message?";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: I see the commented out `fireData` line in your code up there.  Why not try setting up a local notification to fire every 30 minutes and see if that works to start with?

Comment: Actually a good idea. I will try it. Thanks

Comment: I found out, that localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitMinute; will repeat the code every minute. But I wanna have a notification every Monday, so do I have to change something in my code? I am not sure if I have to use localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear / NSCalendarUnitWeekday or kCFCalendarUnitWeekOfYear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried out your code in my own simulator and it seems to work just fine.

The only change I would recommend making would be:

```
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;
```

which I found [in this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838839/uilocalnotification-with-repeatinterval-set-nsweekdaycalendarunit-doesnt-trigge).

Also, the compiler will complain if you use lines like:

```
[nowComponents setMinute:08];
```

(as it interprets that as an octal number instead of an integer).  Don't use leading zeros.  Do something like:

```
[nowComponents setMinute:8];
```

Don't forget to [ask your user to enable notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588964/iphone-local-notification-in-simulator), otherwise they simply won't appear.